# Cannot ask new question for 'A question with that title already exists'

Tags: support, caching

I would like to ask a new question of Stack Overflow but this is not possible because all the form fields of an old question will be loaded into the form when I click the 'Ask Question' button. This happens even when I open a different browser, having cleared cache.

When I click 'Post your question' button, the message:

> A question with that title already exists

is blocking me. Of course, because it is my own question, with one answer already!

The original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771245/php-rest-curl-authentication-header-items-missing).

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to re-ask the same question again?

Comment: Why are you trying to ask another question with the same title?

Comment: No, I don't try to re-ask the same question. I want to ask a completely new question. But this is not possible. When I click the 'Ask Question' button, all the form fields of an old question mentioned above, will be loaded into the form!

Comment: What happens if you just replace everything with your new question?

Comment: @Fei, this is working! Maybe this case could be a hint for the developers.

Comment: @Perino Just an idea, but try checking if it's some sort of automatic form filling thing from your browser.

Comment: @Fei, I thought also this way, but this browser is not allowed to cache anything and uses hidden identity features too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's almost certain to have happened is that SO periodically save questions and answers as you're typing them in. That way, if you're disconnected or otherwise interrupted when you're typing the text of a question/answer, it can be restored when you get back to the page.

The cache should be cleared when you post the question/answer. But if you never posted the old question, then it stays there in the cache until you post one. If it were an answer, you could clear the cache by pressing the "discard" link beside "Post Your Answer". But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for "Ask A Question".

Comment: The old question was already posted, also a comment to this questions had existed.

Comment: @Perino: That's why I said "should be cleared", not "was cleared".

Comment: This could be very helpful for the future Nicol, thx!